# How I add Datalines in a ListView without a Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, data-binding, active-directory

I use a ListBox in my ASP.NET Application that display Active Directory Users. Now I want use a ListView but I don't know how I can fill it with Data :(

My Application:

The User input a String (Lastname or a part of this) in a TextBox. Than the ListBox list all AD Users with the same string from the TextBox. The User who use the asp.net application selected a line in the ListBox and about a Button (btn_ShowProperties) he see all Properties of this AD User.

The Code:

```
protected void btnBenutzerSuchen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             //lboxBenutzer is the ListBox
           lboxBenutzer.Items.Clear(); 

           DirectoryEntry Entry =  new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + "Domain");

           string filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(cn=" + txtBenutzer.Text + "*))";

           DirectorySearcher Searcher = new DirectorySearcher(Entry, filter);

              foreach (SearchResult res in Searcher.FindAll())
              {
                    //GetProperty is a Method to get the Informations from AD

                  string Benutzer = GetProperty(res, "sAMAccountName"); 
                  string eMail = GetProperty(res, "mail");
                  string Vorname = GetProperty(res, "givenName");
                  string Nachname = GetProperty(res, "sn");
                  string Telefon = GetProperty(res, "telephoneNumber");

                     //How I make this in a ListView? :(
                  lboxBenutzer.Items.Add(new ListItem(eMail + " | " + Benutzer + " | " + Nachname + ", " + Vorname + " | " + Telefon));
              }

        }
```

My Idea:

I want use a ListView because the representation of a ListBox is not the right. My Problem is it to add a line to the ListView. What can I do :/ ?

PS: Sorry for my bad English. I'm from Germany :P

tarasov

Comment: Btw: you have to mark an answer as answered, or at least vote up, cause like that you wont get any point, and people wont help you that much anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy, a `ListView` is a databound control, therefore you can use the same binding techniques that you would use with any data-bound controls such a `GridVew`, `FormView`, `ListBox`, etc

Since you already have an `Enumerable` (based on your code: `Searcher.FindAll()`), then you only have to bind it:

### ASPX

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="myListView">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("Benutzer") %>' runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("eMail") %>' runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("Vorname") %>' runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("Nachname") %>' runat="server" /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label5" Text='<%# Eval("Telefon") %>' runat="server" /><br />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemSeparatorTemplate>
        <hr />
    </ItemSeparatorTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

### Code to bind it, code behind

```
var q = from s in Searcher.FindAll().OfType<SearchResult>()
        select new
        {
            Benutzer = GetProperty(s, "sAMAccountName"),
            eMail = GetProperty(s, "mail"),
            Vorname = GetProperty(s, "givenName"),
            Nachname = GetProperty(s, "sn"),
            Telefon = GetProperty(s, "telephoneNumber")
        };

this.myListView.DataSource = q;
this.myListView.DataBind();
```

### Edit 1

To add a table layout:

```
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="myListView">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table runat="server" border="1">
                <tr runat="server">
                    <th runat="server">Benutzer</th>
                    <th runat="server">eMail</th>
                    <th runat="server">Vorname</th>
                    <th runat="server">Nachname</th>
                    <th runat="server">Telefon</th>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" id="ItemPlaceholder">
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr runat="server">
                <td runat="server"><%# Eval("Benutzer")%></td>
                <td runat="server"><%# Eval("eMail")%></td>
                <td runat="server"><%# Eval("Vorname")%></td>
                <td runat="server"><%# Eval("Nachname")%></td>
                <td runat="server"><%# Eval("Telefon")%></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: Thank you very much...!!!!! exactly what I was looking for...:) But the Informations will be display vertical and I want it horizontal :/ for example: eMail | Username | Lastname,Firstname | Telephonenumber ^^ ...But you saved my day :)

Comment: Just remove the `<br /> at the end, since the control is based on templates, you can format the data to fit your needs

Comment: ups I have problems with my browser :D :(

Comment: ok thanks..The Informations are horizontal now :)I need a kind of a table now, that list the Informations right in cells

Answer (score 1):

Create a class with all five properties and fill an array of instances of this class. Create a ListView with templates and bind the array to the list view and don't add them manually. Example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx